# Uncheck a group of checkboxes when one of the textbox from that group will check

Tags: jquery

I have created a group of dynamic checkboxes, what i need is when i select a check box withion that group rest of the check boxes need to uncheck if it was already selected. I have created a JS fiddle please check it

**http://jsfiddle.net/kuc2jarw/**

My code

```
$.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
              dataType:'json',
              url : 'getAllRequisitionIds',
              data : JSON.stringify(),
              success : function(data) {
                     // alert("success");
                      if(data!=''){
                        $.each(data, function(i, item) {

 tr = $('<tr/>');
 tr.append($("<td />").html('<input type="checkbox" id="reqid'+i+'" class="reqid" value='+item+'>'));
 tr.append("<td>" + item + "</td>");


                           $('#table_load').append(tr);
                        });


              });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a delegated change event handler to do it

```
//register a change handler for the checkboxes with class reqid
$('#table_load').on('change', '.reqid', function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        //select all elements with class reqid except current one and uncheck them
        $('.reqid').not(this).prop('checked', false)
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay i have updated my JSfiddle please check that http://jsfiddle.net/kuc2jarw/2/